# OAuth 2 Client Credentials - Missing 'grant_type' & Length Required

Tags: oauth2, authentication, httprequest

Trying to connect to an endpoint to receive a token back.

```
Http http = new Http();
httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
request.setHeader('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
request.setHeader('client_id', 'myClientId');
request.setHeader('client_secret', 'myClientSecret');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
request.setEndPoint('https://myendpoint.com/myservice/token');
request.setMethod('POST');
system.debug('grant_type set to:' + request.getHeader('grant_type'));
HttpResponse res = new httpResponse();
system.debug(request);
res = http.send(request);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

I receive the following error back, even though the grant_type header is set:

```
CALLOUT_RESPONSE [13]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}
```

I have also tried putting all of the headers into the endpoint:

```
Http http = new Http();
httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
request.setEndPoint('https://myEndpoint.com/myService/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=myClientSecret&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&ContentLength=1000');
request.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = new httpResponse();
system.debug(request);
res = http.send(request);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

I receive the following error back, even though Content-Length is set:

```
CALLOUT_RESPONSE [7]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Length Required, StatusCode=411]
```

Is there anything wrong with my requests?

Comment: Is the endpoint here an external endpoint or Salesforce's token endpoint?

Comment: This is for an external endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oauth, the grant_type etc. are not sent as headers but as part of the body. You'll want to do something like:

```
Http http = new Http();
httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
request.setEndPoint('https://myendpoint.com/myservice/token');
request.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=myClientSecret');
request.setMethod('POST');
system.debug('grant_type set to:' + request.getHeader('grant_type'));
HttpResponse res = new httpResponse();
system.debug(request);
res = http.send(request);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

This leaves the content-type and content-length headers as headers (which they should be) and puts the other parameters in the body of the POST.

Comment: Perfect. Was really spinning my wheels on this. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 Was about to comment about it.